# Remove the x-axis ticks while keeping the grids (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to remove the ticks on the x-axis but keep the vertical girds. When I do the following I lose both x-axis ticks as well as the grid.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure() 
figr = fig.add_subplot(211)
...
figr.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
figr.xaxsis.grid(True)
```

How can I retain the grid while makeing x-axis ticks invisible?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

By removing the ticks, do you mean remove the tick labels or the ticks themselves?  This will remove the labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xticklabels([])


plt.show()
```

---

If you really want to get rid of the little tick lines, you can add this:

```
for tic in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tic.tick1On = tic.tick2On = False
```

You could [turn the tick **labels** off](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Tick) here too without resorting to the `ax.set_xticklabels([])` "hack" by setting `tic.label1On = tic.label2On = False`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

ax.grid(True)
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.tick1line.set_visible(False)
    tick.tick2line.set_visible(False)
    tick.label1.set_visible(False)
    tick.label2.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ya, this is what I wanted. I just wanted to remove the tick labels.

Comment: Oh cool.  Well, just in case, I also figured out how to remove the little tick lines too :)

Comment: I have two subplots (ax1 and ax2). How can I make the change without changing the individual axes attribute? I mean, is there a way to do something like fig.setxticklables([]) than doing it for axes, such that both ax1 and ax2 get the changes?

Comment: @DurgaDatta -- Not that I know of (although there are people around more knowledgeable of these things than I am).  I think you could do something like `for ax in fig.get_axes(): ax.set_xticklabels([])` after you've done the plotting...  Does that help?

Comment: I get my work done, but I am trying to learn how to set the attributes at once for subplots.

Comment: @DurgaDatta @mgnilson, if `axs` is your array of subplots you can modify their properties 'at once' with `plt.setp(axs, xticklabels=[])`

Comment: How to this directly from the `plt`, i.e., when you don't do `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`?

Comment: @pceccon -- I haven't really used `matplotlib` much for a while, but perhaps `ax = plt.gca()`?

Comment: I would like to complement @mgilson answer with some recent insight. As of early 2020, the recommended way to hide the tick lines is not ```tic.tick1On=False``` anymore. The correct way is now: ```Tick.tick1line.set_visible(False)```.