# Remove dashes from grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

If I run this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0,labelsize=0)
ax.grid(True)
```

I get the following:

[image]

The xaxis ticks and labels don't show (as expected), but some dashes appear on the bottom of the plot (the first three of which I have circled in red).

How can I remove them? I have looked at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid) for grids, but can't find anything.

An answer which teaches me how I could have figured out how to do this by looking at the documentation would be particularly useful.

Comment: The first part of the question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416681/2454357). The second part (how could you have figured that out yourself) is harder. Usually google and stackoverflow are your best friends :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see are the ticklabels, which have size 0. Even zero sized ticks appear as a single dot because of antigraining.

You probably want to set the label off completely

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0,labelbottom=False)
```

You find out about this by looking at the available arguments [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html).